# Animate HTML Background Image Fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website where the background image is stretched to fit the entire screen. There are thumb nails where clicked will change the background image. I am trying to get a cross fade transition to happen when the background images are changing, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Right now, when the thumb nail is clicked, the entire screen (including the content) fades out, then fades in with the correct background image. I don't want the content to fade out... I'm just trying to get only the background images to fade out. I think my problem is that I am telling the entire HTML page to fade out, but I am unsure on how to target just the background image of the entire site.

CSS

```
html {
    background: url(../img/01.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$("#wrapper #thumbs figure img").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');        
    $('html').fadeOut("slow", function() { });
    $('html').fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $('html').css('background', 'url(' + images[id] + ') no-repeat center fixed');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: it would be good if u add a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried using [**Backstretch**](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) ?

Comment: Never heard of Backstretch. Let me look into that :)

Comment: That did exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you :)

Comment: I noticed though... that it performs sluggish in Chrome/Safari when compared to IE/FF/Opera. The transition is not as smooth, but it gets the job done!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't target the HTML element for this, instead use multiple `div`s that are the entire size of the body.  Then you can specify `z-index` to get the appropriate stacking and crossfade two elements at once as desired.

I've put an example of getting this started in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonypawks/vKB68/1/).  While this is an example for a quick way to roll your own background fading, Avinash's answer would likely be better if it can fit your use case.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this technique? What would I do with these `div`s?

Comment: Added a jsFiddle for you using background colors instead of images.

Comment: Thank you Jesse. Your code doesn't lag like Backstretch, but I can't figure out how to make the image full screen and stretch the entire width/height of the screen.

Comment: Try switching both `position: absolute` statements to `position: fixed`.